# Ghostscript is cutting off my ps to png

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ghostscript

Questions about ghostscript and tkinter:

I have made a tkinter program and I want to convert into an image; I want the image to have the same ratio as 8.5 x 12 in paper; I have read that it's 2550x3300 pixels.
How does this translate to canvas coordinates? For now I picked some numbers with a similar ratio, width=1275,height=1650
Also, what exactly is the canvas and its size? I thought it was the length of what I could write in, but then I can set the scroll regions even further than the given width and height.

Basic idea for the canvas code:

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=1275, height=1650, bg='white', highlightthickness=0,
                                scrollregion=(0, 0, 1275, 1650))
        self.hbar = Scrollbar(master, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.hbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
        self.hbar.config(command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.vbar = Scrollbar(master, orient=VERTICAL)
        self.vbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.vbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)

        self.canvas.config(width=1275, height=1650)
        self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand=self.hbar.set, yscrollcommand=self.vbar.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)


        B1=Button(master,text='add image',command= lambda:self.insert_image())
        B1.pack(side=TOP)
```

and here is my Ghostscript related code:

```
def _save(self):

    self.canvas.postscript(file="tmp.ps",colormode='color')

    args = [
        "ps2jpg",  
        "-dSAFER","-dBATCH", "-dNOPAUSE",
        "-sDEVICE=png16m",
        "-sOutputFile=./ABC.png",
        "./tmp.ps"

    ]

    ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)
```

And it seems to cut of at the left and right side.
Then I added parameters such as -dFitPage","-g1275x1650","-dPSFitPage", or even "-g2550x3300" instead of "-g1275x1650", but it creates a different error,
where the top of my canvas ends up in the middle of my saved image. What I want is the top of my canvas to appear at the top of my image.

Thank you.

[image: Image of what my canvas looks like]

[image: how it saves]

Comment: I meant 8.5 by 11 inch

Answer (score 0):

OK, so firstly, the size you have quoted uses '-g' which is the number of pixels. Clearly the actual media size will then depend on the resolution. If I declare the size to be 600x600 and the resolution is 600 dpi then that's 1 inch by 1 inch, if the resolution is 300 dpi, then its 2 inches by 2 inches.

So you can't say 8.5x12 inch (is that supposed to be one of the standard media sizes ?) is 2550x3300 pixels, without also stating the resolution. In fact that can't even be correct. If I assume that 3300 is correct for 12 inch length, then that's a resolution of 275 dpi. If I then figure the width its 2550/275 = 9 inches.

As it happens, the default resolution of the png16m device appears to be 72. So 2550 by 3300 pixels means that your media is 35x45 inches. Not too surprising that you have scroll bars :-)

Of course, its possible that your PostScript program alters the resolution, but since you haven't supplied it to look at, I can't tell.

Now, Postscript co-ordinate systems start (by default) at the bottom left corner which is 0,0 and extend in **both** directions, positive numbers go up, and right, negative numbers go down and left. Yes its entirely possible to specify that part or all of a drawing operation takes place off the media.

You can also alter the co-ordinate system too, but that's probably more complex than you want to get into.

Without seeing your PostScript program, I can't really say why it lies partially off the media, it may be that that's what the program is asking for.

Using FitPage will attempt to fit the requested image to the page, if its too big it will scale it down (linearly, both directions equally) until both the dimensions fit into the media. This will result in white space in one direction unless your media happens to be the same shape as the program requested. That smallest dimension is then centered. I don't recall exactly but I think if the program marks fit into the media, then it just centres it.

So basically, you need to get the dimensions correct to start with. Assuming you are happy with a 72 dpi output image, and that your media is genuinely 8.5x12 inches, then you can specify -g612x864. If the rendered image doesn't fit precisely then its probable that your program makes marks off the media, is using a different media size, or 'something'. Can't say what without seeing the PostScript.

If you can share a simple PostScript file I can look at it (I can't use anything that requires me to use tkinter, sorry) and give you some more detailed guidance.

[EDIT]

So the output is actually an EPS, not a PostScript program, we can see this from the initial comments (any line beginning with '%' is a comment):

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%Creator: Tk Canvas Widget
%%Title: Window .49823304L
%%CreationDate: Mon Aug 14 23:47:27 2017
%%BoundingBox: -171 85 785 707
```

%!PS tells us its a PostScript program, -Adobe-3.0 tells us it conforms to version 3.0 of the Document Structure Convention (a way of creating PostScript programs that makes them more portable for non PostScript interpreters) and the EPSF tells us its **actually** an EPS, finally the trailing -3.0 declares that it conforms to version 3.0 of the EPS specification.

Now EPS files are not intended to be sent directly to a PostScript interpreter. They are supposed to be included inside other PostScript programs and used as a kind of 'black box'. This technique is often used when the object is something like a company logo which does not change, or when you send work to an outside agency (eg a freelance graphic artist) they may send it as an EPS for you to use.

The EPS conforms to certain rules regarding what it can and can't contain. One of the important things it **cannot** do is set the media size. Execution of setpagedevice can cause the device to reset the marked content, which would throw away any marks made before the media selection.

Additionally, the EPS doesn't know how big its going to be when drawn on the final page. You could think of a logo being drawn large on the front page, then drawn small in the footer of each page for example.

So what the EPS contains is a declaration of where it marks the page, this is given by the BoundingBox:

```
%%BoundingBox: -171 85 785 707
```

Now you will note that the BoundingBox of this EPS begins at -179,85 and extends to 785,707. So its width is 964 and its height is 792. Those are in PostScript5 units which are 1/72 of an inch. So your EPS is actually 13.38 inches wide by 12 inches tall. Not only that, but it begins 2.48 inches off the left edge of the media.

This probably explains why you are having trouble getting the output you want, you probably are not setting the media correctly in Ghostscript, and translating the origin so that the left edge doesn't lie off the media.

Its the job of the application which places the EPS in its own PostScript output to translate and scale the co-ordinate system so that the EPS is at the required position and size on the final media.

So you have a choice; you can create a PostScript program which sets up the Current Transformation Matrix appropriately to scale and position the EPS, and then includes the EPS in its entirety, finishign with a showpage to actually render it (EPS files may not include a showpage for obvious reasons)

Or you can use the -dEPSCrop or EPSFitPage switches in Ghostscript (documented [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.21/Use.htm#EPS_parameters)) which will fit the content to the page, or the page to the content. Note that the precise behaviour of the FitPage switch depends on the exact version of Ghostscript you are using, which you haven't mentioned. The documentation there is for the current version, 9.21.

If you create a PostScript program yourself to do the work then you have complete control over how its rendered, if you let Ghostscript do it then you have less control but its simple to do. Your choice really.

NB the pastebin stops abruptly and makes no actual marks, so its not a valid PostScript program. If you put the whole file on DropBox or soemthing I could perhaps be more specific, but the gist is certainly covered above.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got those pixel numbers from a google search.

Comment: Let me correct myself, I meant 11 not 12, so then it would be 792.So the postscript file generated by tkinter is too long to include on here, it goes past the char limit. I'll add a pastebin link.One thing I've noticed is when I make the canvas 612x792 and the  args in ghostscript -g612x792 , plus fit the page, it works. Anything different messes it up.

Comment: Well at 72 dpi, 612x792 is exactly 8.5x11 inches. So if your PostScript program uses an exact media size of 8.5x11 inches, then it will fit. If you use a different media size to that required by the program, then either bits will fall off (if the media is too small) or you will get white space (if the media is too big). If the media is too small then FitPage scales both directions equally, so using that will only fit one direction (the largest), the other will have white space on each side. I'll take a look at your PostScript when you post a link, I can't see it anywhere at the moment.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/aUdfGiD1  I chopped off the part that is probably the encoding of the canvas, its mostly a bunch of F's and it exceeded the limit for pastebin too

Comment: OK well the important point here is what you have posted is not a PostScript program, its an EPS (Encapsulated PostScript) file. I'll edit my answer above.

Comment: So for the late response, I was taking a break from the project for a bit.  Taking the fact that its an EPS in account hasn't changed much, so for now I am just sticking with the fact that 612x792 works and moving onto other parts of the app.